# Assert\Url does validates invalid urls in Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have been adding some constraints in my form/url, and when testing it, I realized that it would actually accept any types of string???

Here is my code:

```
namespace OC\PrepBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Video
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="video")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="OC\PrepBundle\Repository\VideoRepository")
 */
class Video
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="video_url", type="text")
     *
     * @Assert\UrL(
     *     message ="This url is not valid",
     *     checkDNS = true
     *     )
     *
     */
    private $videourl;
```

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to fill you form with a non-url string ?

Comment: also try to add:  protocols = {"http", "https", "ftp"} as you can see in the doc

Comment: Show us your controller please

Comment: try with the correct case: `Assert\Url` instead of `Assert\UrL`

Comment: I did change it but just wanted to to try like the example on the Symfony web site

Comment: I tried with non url only to trigger the error message as a negative testing but it went through

Comment: I thought by putting Assert\Url() would default to http and https

Comment: Ill try all that anyway thanks

Comment: Something tells me the error is not in the constraint but in the controller/service you're using to persist your entity. As @Mcsky suggested, edit your question to include your controller code.

Comment: We can't help you without the code using the constraint